# conversion of a local xml file to pdf fillable form

Tags: xml, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4, itext

Every time user can't fill up the form. So, i want to automate this thing with a pdf fillable form from my local XML file which contains user data in XML Format.
i have seen similar question in stackoverflow [XML to PDF fillable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003337/xml-to-fillable-pdf-form)

which i tried to understand for a long time but i couldn't. I tried exploring other ways.

Is there any Gems or plugins for XML to PDF forms.

Please suggest me the Procedure for automating it.

Any experience on this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear (nor was the question you refer to). Your question already goes awry from the first sentence "Every time user can't fill up the form." What do you mean by that? Does a user have to fill out a form in a web application? You say you have a local XML file containing user data. If that is true, what extra data do you require from the user and how do you want to obtain it? You say you tried exploring other ways: can you tell us which ways? You should clarify if you want a useful answer.

Comment: In my web application user will enter details in form, whatever details user entered it will store in a xml file which i have in app/public folder. Now my question is deatils in xml file should populate to pdf fillable form and then its downloaded. The pdf have the same fields which user entered

Comment: In that case, your question is way too broad. You have many different options. Going from storing the submitted fields as XFDF and then merging the XFDF with an AcroForm, parsing the XML and fill out an AcroForm, injecting the XML into an XFA form, using XSLT to transform the XML into HTML and then use XML Worker to create the PDF, using XML Worker as a generic XML to PDF engine, etc... You need to make a choice based on what you think is best for you. Maybe you should start reading the documentation. There are examples aplenty.