# User-fillable PDF form (or other fillable format) from which to generate XML data (or JSON)

Tags: xml, json, pdf

Right now, we have a static and generic form, as a Word document (many tables basically).
This Word doc is sent to people that fill it in and send it back.
Once we get the Word doc back, we have to copy-paste the filled-in values into an web-based form that we use internally.

The idea is that copy-pasting values from Word into the webform takes forever and it's annoying to do.

Of course, the most obvious solution is to send a link to this webform instead of a Word doc so that people fill in the webform directly. However, that's not possible for too many reasons.

So given that I'm stuck with the constraint of "sending someone a file or something and then getting it back", I was thinking the simplest way was to send a fillable PDF that'd be filled in and sent back. Once the filled-in PDF is returned, computer-parsable data (XML or JSON or whatever) would be extracted.

---

So that's the idea but I don't understand how to create a PDF (or another common format) that can:

- be filled in by the user
- have the filled-in information extracted/exported from PDF into something like JSON or XML

I read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003337/xml-to-fillable-pdf-form/15004865#15004865) and I created fillable PDF but once the PDF was filled, I could not extract the info as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Export the data from the filled PDF as XFDF, the XML representation of the (PDF-native) Forms Data Format.

Or instead of the user sending you back a filled PDF, use the Submit function, with XFDF as submit format.

XFDF has a very simple schema, and therefore, transformation to what you exactly may need should not be a big deal.